# PHP use SoapClient don't add namespace to child nodes in request envelope

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to get a SoapRequest to work, and the requirements doesn't seem to work well with the standard PHP soap client.

I've simplified the code, but the problem should still be apparent:

I'm doing this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
$client->MakeRequest([
  'root' => [
    'attribute' => 'value',
    'node' => [...]
  ]
]);
```

Which ends op making a request like this

```
<ns1:root attributes="value">
  <ns1:node>...</ns1:node>
</ns1:root>
```

But what I actually need is for the request to look like this.

```
<ns1:root attributes="value">
  <node>...</node>
</ns1:root>
```

I have tried a lot of different solutions using `SoapVar` for different part of the data structure, but I never end up with what I want, either my issue is that attributes are converted to nodes or that the root namespace (from the WSDL definition) is added to child nodes which makes the 3rd party service I'm integrating with fail.

Is there any trick or library which can help me with this, so I can avoid manually building the XML and sending it to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only method is to create `SoapVar` with adequate namespace definition using `SOAP_ENC_OBJECT` encoding:

```
new \SoapVar($val, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, $nodeName, $namespace);
```

And call this inside your recursive function. AFAIR, it's the only solution to achieve namespace insertion for children.